# Add or AddRange to List in C# Initialize Object

Tags: c#, .net, initialization

As explained in https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/visualstudio/code-quality/ca2227?view=vs-2019 I've got an object with a read only list like this:

```
public class MyClass {
  public int id { get; set; }
  public List<string> stringList { get; } = new List<string>;
}
```

But how can I initialize `MyClass` by adding data to `stringList`?

```
MyClass test = new MyClass(){
  id = 1,
  stringList = ???
}
```

Comment: You can pass your data to your class constructor and add them to your readonly list.

Answer (score 3):

You can use not very obvious syntax with [collection initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#collection-initializers):

```
var x = new MyClass
{
    id = 1,
    stringList = {"as", "ddsd"} // will ADD "as", "ddsd" to stringList 
};
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", x.stringList)); // prints as, ddsd
```

Bur usual approach to handle readonly properties (until C# 9 is released with [init only properties and records](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/welcome-to-c-9-0/)) is to pass initialization values in constructor.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add one or more elements to the list, you can use the solution proposed by @GuruStron.

```cs
var x = new MyClass
{
    id = 1,
    stringList = {"as", "ddsd"}
};
```

However, this doesn't work if you want to add a collection. This example won't compile:

```cs
var collection = new[] {"as", "ddsd"};

var x = new MyClass
{
    id = 1,
    stringList = { collection } // compile error!
};
```

But you can create your own custom c# [collection initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#collection-initializers). Create an extension method called `Add`:

```cs
public static TCollection Add<TCollection, TItem>(
    this TCollection destination,
    IEnumerable<TItem> source)
    where TCollection : ICollection<TItem>
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(destination);
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(source);

    if (destination is List<TItem> list)
    {
        list.AddRange(source);
        return destination;
    }

    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        destination.Add(item);
    }

    return destination;
}
```

Now the previous example compiles:

```cs
var collection = new[] {"as", "ddsd"}

var x = new MyClass
{
    id = 1,
    stringList = { collection }
};
```

I suggest putting the extension method under the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace, so it will be automatically imported without need to manually add required `using`.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the `stringList` as a parameter in the constructor and assign the property to the parameter:

```
public class MyClass {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public List<string> stringList { get; } = new List<string>();

    public MyClass(List<string> stringList) {
        this.stringList = stringList;
    }
}
```

Comment: This ill not work because stringList  is read only. You have to add items to existing list: `this.stringList.AddRange(stringList);`

Comment: @Ben Yes it will because you can initialize a readonly property from the constructor.

Comment: The real issue is the missing `()` after `new List<string>`